# Cordova TTS plugin not working Moto X Play devices

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, text-to-speech

I have a **Cordova** project with **[this](https://github.com/domaemon/org.apache.cordova.plugin.tts)** Text To Speech (TTS) plugin installed. This plugin working fine all other devices including IOS and Android except **Moto X Play device**. Is there any device specific issue with this phone?

Answer (score 0):

This is bacause Text-To-Speech(TTS) is disabled in the device. You can enable it through

`Settings > Language & Input > Text-to-speech`

or you could install [Google TTS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts)